# Hiding all elements with the same class name?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide elements with the same class name (float_form), but I'm also trying to use the script below to show them (all of the float_form class divs are initially hidden). I've looked at a lot of jquery solutions, but I can't seem to make any of them work for this.

```
function show(a) {
    var e = document.getElementById(a);
    if (!e) 
        return true;

    if (e.style.display == "none") {
        e.style.display = "block"
    } else {
        e.style.display = "none"
    }
    return true;
}
​
```

**Edit:** Sorry if it wasn't clear, I do not intend to use Jquery(and I know that this is not jquery). I am looking for a way to use javascript to recognize repeated classnames that are not in style= display:none; without compromising the show/hide ID element since there is a loop with the div id as the key. The html for the div looks like below, with {item.ID} being a while loop.

```
 <div class="float_form" id="{item.ID}" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: Your code has zero jQuery. **JavaScript is not jQuery**!. Your shown code selects an element by id, not by class name. For the latter, use `document.getElementsByClassName`, and loop through all items in the returned list.

Comment: @RobW. Shall we add the jQuery tag? I answered both vanilla js and jQuery.

Comment: Even after your edit it's very, very unclear what is it that you're asking\need.

Comment: Well that's annoying, people want you make them their job, and don't even spend the time say what they want. [Sound like a help vampire to me](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**vanilla javascript**

```
function toggle(className, displayState){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className)

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].style.display = displayState;
    }
}

toggle('float_form', 'block'); // Shows
toggle('float_form', 'none'); // hides
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.float_form').show(); // Shows
$('.float_form').hide(); // hides
```

Comment: +1 but unfortunately `getElementsByClassName` only works on recent versions of the browsers.

Comment: @undefined. He can use jQuery if he wants to, or implement `getElementsByClassName` if he likes to. He should put a lot more effort in his questions, I don't event know if he's really using jQuery or not.

Comment: @undefined. Well that's annoying, people want you make them their job, and don't even spend the time say what they want. [Sound like a help vampire to me](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)

Comment: you are right, it's frustrating, especially when they ask a question and comeback next week to check the answers while people who try to solve the problem are battling each other.

Answer (score 15):

If you're looking into jQuery, then it's good to know that you can use a class selector inside the parameters of `$` and call the method `.hide()`.

```
$('.myClass').hide(); // all elements with the class myClass will hide.
```

But if it's a toggle you're looking for, use `.toggle();`

But here's my take on a good toggle **without** using jQuery:

```
function toggle( selector ) {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll( selector ),
      node,
      styleProperty = function(a, b) {
        return window.getComputedStyle ? window.getComputedStyle(a).getPropertyValue(b) : a.currentStyle[b];
      };

  [].forEach.call(nodes, function( a, b ) {
    node = a;

    node.style.display = styleProperty(node, 'display') === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
  });

}

toggle( '.myClass' );
```

Demo here (Click "Render" to run): http://jsbin.com/ofusad/2/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 4):

Using jquery

```
$(".float_form").each(function(){
    if($(this).css("display") == "none"){
        $(this).show();
    }else{
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

## No jQuery needed

```
const toggleNone = className => {
  let elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className)
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    if (elements[i].style.display === "none") {
      elements[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      elements[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

const toggleVisibility = className => {
  let elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className)
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    if (elements[i].style.visibility === "hidden") {
      elements[i].style.visibility = "";
    } else {
      elements[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }
}

// run 
toggleNone('your-class-name-here'); // toggles remove
// or run 
toggleVisibility('your-class-name-here'); // toggles hide
```

#### Answer provided in ES6 syntax but easily can be converted to ES5 if you wish

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
function showClass(a){
 var e = [];
 var e = getElementsByClassName(a);
 for(i in e ){
    if(!e[i])return true;

    if(e[i].style.display=="none"){
       e[i].style.display="block"
    } else {
       e[i].style.display="none"
    }
 }
 return true;
}
```

**demo** : `showClass("float_form");`

Comment: Because the ID element is being used for an array loop, I need to keep the getElementById. I tried using this separately with a hidden input button but it didn't work either.

Comment: @user1489970 it's a new function `showClass()`, just keep `show()` function you already have, and add this

Comment: I did try using it separately (and parsing var e in as var f into the original function). Only the original function worked.