# Show steps one at a time

Tags: jquery, html

I run a tutorial website that has a jQuery script to show instructions one at a time, by clicking the 'Next Step' button. When there are no more steps, the code hides the 'Next Step' button and shows the 'Next Tutorial' button. Here is the code for this...

```js
var stepNumber = 1;
$(function() {
  $('p.step:nth-child(' + stepNumber + ')').show();
  $('#nextstep').click(function() {
    $('p.step:nth-child(' + stepNumber+++')').show();
    $('p.step:nth-child(' + stepNumber + ')').fadeIn();
    if (stepNumber == $('p.step').length) {
      $('#nextstep').hide();
      $('#nexttut').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pad">
  <p class="step">
    1
  </p>
  <p class="step">
    2
  </p>
  <p class="step">
    3
  </p>
  <p class="step">
    4
  </p>
  <p class="step">
    5
  </p>
  <p id="nextstep"><a href="#!" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Next Step">Next Step</a>
  </p>
  <p id="nexttut"><a href="#!" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Next Tutorial">Next Tutorial</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

This script can be used on any number of steps, without changing any of the jQuery.

My problem is that it has no function whatsoever. I am fairly new to jQuery and I can't spot anything wrong. Can you?

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbkew6tk/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to hide all .step initially. Use following CSS to do that.

```
.step{
    display: none;
}
```

**Full Code**

```js
var stepNumber = 1;

$('p.step:nth-child(' + stepNumber + ')').show();
$('#nextstep').click(function() {
  $('p.step:nth-child(' + stepNumber++ + ')').show();
  $('p.step:nth-child(' + stepNumber + ')').fadeIn();
  if (stepNumber == $('p.step').length) {
    $('#nextstep').hide();
    $('#nexttut').show();
  }
});
```

```css
.step{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pad">
  <p class="step">
    1
  </p>
  <p class="step">
    2
  </p>
  <p class="step">
    3
  </p>
  <p class="step">
    4
  </p>
  <p class="step">
    5
  </p>
  <p id="nextstep"><a href="#!" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Next Step">Next Step</a></p>
  <p id="nexttut"><a href="#!" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Next Tutorial">Next Tutorial</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide div when document load,(Credit : gdoron [answer from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11254429/hiding-all-elements-with-the-same-class-name))

```js
 var stepNumber = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.step').hide();
});
$(function(){
    $('p.step:nth-child(' + stepNumber + ')').show();
    $('#nextstep').click(function(){
        $('p.step:nth-child(' + stepNumber++ + ')').show();
        $('p.step:nth-child(' + stepNumber + ')').fadeIn();
        if(stepNumber == $('p.step').length) {
            $('#nextstep').hide();
            $('#nexttut').show();
        }
    });
});
$(function() {
  $('p.step:nth-child(' + stepNumber + ')').show();
  $('#nextstep').click(function() {
    $('p.step:nth-child(' + stepNumber+++')').show();
    $('p.step:nth-child(' + stepNumber + ')').fadeIn();
    if (stepNumber == $('p.step').length) {
      $('#nextstep').hide();
      $('#nexttut').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pad">
  <p class="step">
    1
  </p>
  <p class="step">
    2
  </p>
  <p class="step">
    3
  </p>
  <p class="step">
    4
  </p>
  <p class="step">
    5
  </p>
  <p id="nextstep"><a href="#!" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Next Step">Next Step</a>
  </p>
  <p id="nexttut"><a href="#!" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Next Tutorial">Next Tutorial</a>
  </p>
</div>
```